# 404 error with MapPageRoute() routing a aspx page within a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Trying to route in webforms, getting a 404.
I have set up my global.asax.cs file as follows using `System.Web.Routing;`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("ProfilePage",
            "Profile",
            "~/Manager/Profile.aspx");
        }
```

profile.aspx is located within the manager folder. No idea why it's not working. Would be grateful if someone could make some suggestions I am fairly new to asp.net.

I am expecting the url `localhost:60008/Manager/Profile/` to load the Profile.aspx page.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? What isn't happen that you expect to happen? What URL are you trying to use?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter specifies the URL. Try:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ProfilePage",
                    "Manager/Profile",
                    "~/Manager/Profile.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it right the first time. Here a valid routing

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "YourPage", "~/Your/full/url.aspx", true);
```

The first para can be let empty, the second is the one you are going to use, the third is the url of your page, the last [optional] is to check if the file exist physically or not.

I believe where the error comes is how you use it, for a hyperlink you would say

```
NavigateUrl="~/YourPage"
```

In a html anchor

```
href="~/YourPage" runat="server"
```

In the browser address bar it will show like this http://YourDomain.com/YourPage/

That's the way it works for me. Personally having to put the folders in there defeat the purpose of using routing no?